# How to override "WebKit Built in pdf" of safari 10 with adobe pdf?

Tags: safari

I want to override "webkit built in pdf" of safari 10 with adobePDFViewer.plugin, so that navigator.plugins in JavaScript could detect adobePDFViewer Plugin instead of "WebKit Built in pdf"

here what i am getting plugin array from navigator.plugins in console of latest safari 10.

platform: "MacIntel"

plugins: PluginArray

0: Plugin {0: MimeType, 1: MimeType, 2: MimeType, name: "WebKit built-in PDF", filename: "", description: "", length: 3, item: function, …}

length: 1

PluginArray Prototype

product: "Gecko"

productSub: "20030107"

userAgent: "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12) AppleWebKit/602.1.50 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/10.0 Safari/602.1.50"

vendor: "Apple Computer, Inc."

vendorSub: ""

webdriver: undefined

Comment: Thanks i found why it's not happening..!

Answer (score 0):

Hello Every one i found answer to this solution myself...!
As of now Safari and other latest browsers and Firefox restricts enumeration via navigator[] array of objects, which means that it does not allow plugins to content enumerating navigator.plugins[]. This change does not disable any plugins; it just hides some plugins names from enumeration.

Taken from https://wiki.mozilla.org/Fingerprinting
In theory, all plugin names could be cloaked because web content can query navigator.plugins[] by plugin name. Unfortunately, we could not cloak all plugin names because many popular websites check for Flash or QuickTime by enumerating navigator.plugins[] and comparing plugin names one by one, instead of just asking for navigator.plugins["Shockwave Flash"] by name. These websites should be fixed.

```
 for (plugin of navigator.plugins) { console.log(plugin.name); }

 "Shockwave Flash"
 "QuickTime Plug-in 7.7.3"
 "Default Browser Helper"
 "Unity Player"
 "Google Earth Plug-in"
 "Silverlight Plug-In"
 "Java Applet Plug-in"
 "Adobe Acrobat NPAPI Plug-in, Version 11.0.18"
 "WacomTabletPlugin"

  navigator.plugins["Adobe Acrobat NPAPI Plug-in, Version 11.0.18"].name // get cloaked plugin by name

  "Adobe Acrobat NPAPI Plug-in, Version 11.0.18"
```